# Missing required parameter for [Route: categoryfilms.update] [URI: admin/categoryfilms/{categoryfilm}] [Missing parameter: categoryfilm]

Tags: php

Going to edit category film page laravel can't get id even though I pass it. I recently started learning laravel, don't throw stones
This my Controller:

```
public function update(CategoryFilmRequest $request, CategoryFilm $categoryFilm)
    {
        $categoryFilm->update($request->validated());

        return redirect(route('categoryfilms.index'));
    }
```

This my create.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ isset($categoryFilm) ? route('categoryfilms.update', $categoryFilm->id) : route('categoryfilms.store') }}" method="POST">
```

Tried a lot of things but nothing worked

Comment: The title should be concise. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have two separate forms for adding and updating the categoryfilms table.

For updating a value use this code in your controller:

```
    public function update(Request $request, CategoryFilm $categoryFilm){
       /*if you want to validate input*/
       $validator = \Validator::make(
         $request->all(), [
            'categoryname' => 'required',/*assuming there is an input with "categoryname" in name value i,e name="categoryname" */
         ]
       );
       if($validator->fails()){
          $messages = $validator->getMessageBag();
          return redirect()->back()->with('error', $messages->first());
       }
       $categoryFilm->active = $request->validated();//i am not quite sure what validated() is supposed to be doing here
       $categoryFilm->update();
     }
```

In your blade action have it as follows:

```
<form action="{{route('categoryfilms.update', $categoryFilm->id)}}" method="post">
    /*your form code goes here*/
</form>
```

For adding a new value use this code in your controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    /*if you want to validate input*/
    $validator = \Validator::make(
        $request->all(), [
            'categoryname' => 'required',/*assuming there is an input with "categoryname" in name value i,e name="categoryname" */
        ]
    );
    if($validator->fails())
    {
            $messages = $validator->getMessageBag();
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', $messages->first());
    }
    /*if you want to validate input*/
    $categoryFilm           = new $categoryFilm();//make sure this model(categoryFilm) exists in your model folder
    $categoryFilm->active   = $request->validated();//i am not quite sure what validated() is supposed to be doing here
    /*assuming you have other values you want to store in categoryfilm database table*/
    $categoryFilm->VALUE1   = $request->INPUT-NAME-FROM-FORM;//repeat this for any other fields.
    /*assuming you have other values you want to store in categoryfilm database table*/
    $categoryFilm->save();

    return redirect()->route('categoryfilms.index')->with('success', __('Added successfully.'));//assuming you have an index(or whatever you've named it) blade file in categoryfilms folder
}
```

In your blade action have it as follows:

```
<form action="{{route('categoryfilms.store')}}" method="post">
    /*your form code goes here*/
</form>
```

**NOTE:** Laravel uses "**snake case**", the plural name of the class so if you make a mistake naming these it's highly likely to result in this error(talking from personal experience)